# Motif and X11 with Emscripten and WASM

Tags: c++, x11, webassembly, emscripten, motif

For a webpage that I'm doing I'm trying to integrate some very old legacy code into a web browser using Web Assembly and C++. This legacy code uses Motif an old C++ front end framework. I was unable to find any information on whether or not this is actually possible. Does anyone have any idea? Thank you.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motif_(software)

Comment: You want to re-use your legacy code to render Motif/X11 API calls in a web browser?

Comment: *Possible*? Anything's possible. *Probable*? Not as much. *Practical*? Nah. You'd be better off re-writing to the original functionality using a modern browser framework rather than setting up a browser X11 server and trying to get Motif to run on it. I could be way off base; if there's a working browser X11 server you might be part of the way there--but probably less far than you'd think.

Comment: */me currently experiencing flashbacks*

Comment: For reasons, it's one of our only options. Obviously long term, it would be great to just rewrite everything into Typescript or whatever. Basically yeah. we have a GUI application built in Motif. Rather than rewriting the whole thing, we need a relatively quick solution to get it in a web browser.

Comment: if ported more or less directly you'll need some sort of X11 server to be running inside same web page. Maybe worth investigating if you can compile with some Motif variation / port that renders to framebuffer / sdl instead of x11 backend.

Comment: Googling stuff like "html5 x11 server" turns up https://xpra.org/, which might be all you need.